# Update Webpack entry points without restarting

Tags: webpack

I have a webpack config with multiple entry points. I also have a central json file that holds data for everything in my project.
When I change something in my json I am able to tell which portion of the project it affects. This is usually only one of the many entry points but webpack recompiles the entire thing - all entry points - each time which is getting noticeably slow.

Is there a way to tell webpack to only run a sub set of its entry points based on some variable?
Or to rebuild the entry points each time a code change is detected and a compilation is  triggered?

Thanks